# How to Update progress bar in status bar while file upload occurs using a Service?

Tags: android, service, notifications, progress-bar

I have researched this and not found a clear answer that has a combination of progress bar + status bar + Service? My issue is that the way file upload is implemented, (that being the only way it can because the server supports it like this), I cannot keep track of number of bytes being written. Hence, I cannot increment the progress bar correctly to reflect the accurate file upload status.
The current implementation increments the progress bar, does the upload and removes the progress bar once it reaches 100. BUT that progress is not accurate reflection of the upload. The upload happens much earlier yet the bar keeps ON. I would rather have the progress showing while this request/response is occurring.
Following is my code snippet:

```
  public class UploadFileService extends IntentService {
    public UploadFileService() {
super("UploadFileService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    fName = intent.getExtras().getString(Constants.EXTRA_K_FILENAME);
    path = intent.getExtras().getString(Constants.EXTRA_K_FILEPATH);
            attribute = intent.getExtras().getString(Constants.EXTRA_K_ATTRIBUTE);

//Start thread to doFilepUpload
uploadthread = new UploadThread(fName, path, attribute);
uploadthread.start();
```

}

// Define the Handler that receives messages from the thread and update the progress

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        Integer total = msg.arg1;
        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, total, false);
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);



        if ( total.equals(100)  && getResponse() != null ){
            // inform the progress bar of updates in progress
            uploadthread.setState(UploadThread.STATE_DONE);

            Intent broadcastIntent = prepareBroadcast();
            // remove the notification (we're done)
            nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }
};


public class UploadThread extends Thread {

    private String name;
    private String path;
    private String attribute;
    final static int STATE_DONE = 0;
    final static int STATE_RUNNING = 1;
    int mState;
    int total;


    public UploadThread(String fName, String path, String attribute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name = fName;
        this.path = path;
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setResponse(doFileUpload(name, path, attribute));

        if( getResponse() != null){
                            // house keeping for the application
            if(response.result.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                saveFileName = response.data.savedFileName;
                responseMessage = response.message;
            }else if (response.result.equalsIgnoreCase("error") || 
         response ==  null ){
                responseMessage = response.message; 
                saveFileName = null;
                originalName = fName;
            }
        }

        mState = STATE_RUNNING;   
        total = 0;
        while (mState == STATE_RUNNING && total <=100) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "^^ Thread.sleep");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Logger.e("ERROR", "Thread Interrupted");
            }
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
            msg.arg1 = total;
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
            total++;
        }
    }

    /* sets the current state for the thread,
     * used to stop the thread */
    public void setState(int state) {
        mState = state;
    }

}
```

Does anyone have suggestions/ideas on how I can update progress bar to show correct upload progress?
File Upload process:

```
    paramString = p.getName()+"="+URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(), HTTP.UTF_8);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unsupported encoding --> 
           name="+p.getName()+"; value="+p.getValue(), e);
                        throw e;
                    }
                    if (combinedParams.length() > 1) {
                        combinedParams += "&" + paramString;
                    } else {
                        combinedParams += paramString;
                    }
                }
            }

            request = new HttpPost(url + combinedParams);

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

            // add headers
            for (NameValuePair h : headers) {               
                request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
            }

            // add cookies
            for(NameValuePair c : cookies) {            
                request.addHeader(H_COOKIE,          
                         c.getName()+"="+c.getValue());                 
            }           
                 entity.addPart(uploadFile.getName(), new FileBody(uploadFile));

            request.setEntity(entity)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `AsyncTask` for your uploading job? It allows you to use `publishProgress()` from where you'll broadcast to the UI whenever you call this method...?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski: I did try AsyncTask but due to some issues like uploading one file at a time, Service seemd to be the best option for this app.

Comment: if you are doing it from Service why bother with threads, since service is running on separate process, which will not cause any UI-freeze in your activity. Just find a way how you'll calculate the progress of the upload. It's ok to run threads from service, I fully understand...this is my brief thought...

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski: Actually that is my Question and road block right now:" calculating the progress of the upload"

Comment: progress = file.getTotalSpace() - (file.getTotalSpace()-uploaded); perhaps :D and then find the percentage using simple math to transform the progress into the progress bar, where max of the progressbar will be the total size of file...

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around to this problem. It is not an ideal solution but due to the fact that counting of bytes is not possible I resorted to this route. In the upload Service that I created, I have 2 different threads. Thread #1, does the upload and Thread #2, maintains the progress bar in the notification area. Thread #2 depends on #1. While #1 is alive, thread #2 increments by 1 and sleeps 1sec and with each progress increment, the sleep interval increases by 0.2secs. If the upload completes at lets say 45%, the progress bar jumps to 100%.